# Destroying dependencies with Ant Migration Tool

Tags: formula-field, migration-tool, ant, delete

I have a very simple case that I'm surprised Salesforce migration tool can't deal with.

I have two date fields on Account: Open and Closed.

I then have a formula field that sets a boolean to true if today is between Open and Closed.

These are stored in an unmanaged package.

So far so good. But when  I try and destroy these changes (rename package.xml to destructiveChanges.xml, create empty package.xml) I get the following error:

1. objects/Account.object (Account.Open_Date__c) -- Error: This custom field is
   referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. : Custom Formula Field - Account.Active
   __c.

But my destructiveChanges should destroy all fields included, the date fields *and* related formula.

Do I have to bash out staged destructions, ie figure out which fields are formula fields, destroy those, then destroy other fields? These seems horrible and I was hoping the tool would be smart enough to recognise that the destruction is self contained.

*[Cross post from Salesforce Developer Forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AzcjIAC)*

Comment: Can you provide more background about *"I then have a formula field that sets a boolean to true if today is between Open and Closed*"? Are you using Workflow, ProcessBuilder, Trigger or what? A pure formula can't update other fields

Comment: Sorry @UweHeim it's been over two years since I posted this question. At a guess I'd say it was a regular formula field and my wording was clumsy. It should have been "I then have a formula field whose boolean value is True if today is between Open and Closed"

Answer (score 3):

My understating is that you always need to be explicit on what is included in the [destructive change](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm).

While inconvenient that you need to list out every component to be deleted it is a good safety feature.

Imagine you test it out in a sandbox and it implicitly deleted **all** the dependent components from those fields. You knew there was only a formula field that would be deleted in addition to the fields, so that was fine.

However, you then do the same against production, and it implicitly deletes additional workflows and triggers that also depended on those fields but weren't yet present in your sandbox org as another admin or developer created them independently. Guess who won't be a popular person when that happens!

So, yes it's inconvenient to have to explicitly delete the dependencies, but it is much safer in the long run for something that can have large and irreversible affects.

---

With regards to problems with explicitly deleting dependencies in a single metadata api call. See the Spring '15 (v33.0) feature: [Delete Components before and after Component Updates](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_deploy_delete.htm): (my emphasis)

> You can control when components are deleted in a deployment. Use a manifest to specify component deletions before updates, and use another manifest to specify component deletions after updates. Specifying the processing order of deletions relative to component updates **provides you with greater flexibility and enables you to delete components with dependencies**.

You can use a `destructiveChangesPre.xml` and `destructiveChangesPost.xml` to split the dependencies as required.

Consider voting for the idea: [destructiveChanges should delete dependencies if all components are included](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003Vl2QAE)

Comment: But even when you explicitly list 2 fields where one has a dependency on the other, it will throw an error saying that the "child" field has a dependency on the "parent". The only workaround I found was to list the "parents" in a separate destructiveChanges list and delete it *first*

Comment: @brezotom I believe you can now use the [`destructiveChangesPre.xml` and `destructiveChangesPost.xml` manifests](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_deploy_delete.htm) that were introduced in the Spring '15 release (v33.0). This would allow you to split the dependencies into to stages

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve much, considering that the annoyance is needing to find dependencies and delete parents first. Creating 2 xml files one for pre and one for post is just as tedious as creating 2 entirely separate packages

Comment: @brezotom True, it still puts the onus on you to identify and split off the dependency. Still, at least you can do it all in a single deploy. You could raise an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) to see if Salesforce will simplify the process.

Comment: @brezotom If you do raise an idea, please mention the link back here so it can be promoted to anyone who runs into the same thing in the future.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003Vl2QAE

Comment: Wildcards aren't supported in destructive changes, so you always have to be explicit. Attempting to use wildcards would cause a different error. The pre and post thing is fine, I guess, but a bit unwieldy. Salesforce seems to manage fine with other metadata that reference each other and are destroyed at the same time.

Comment: @powlo I've included the idea that brezotom created that would remove the pre/post split requirement. At this stage I think it is best we can do.